# CSS content not shown on Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

It should show a star, which works in Firefox, but not in Chrome and not in Opera. Even if I just use a normal letter in the content, it is not shown, so it is not related to FontAwesome.

Ideas?

```css
hr.star-light:after,
hr.star-primary:after {
  content: "\f005";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -.8em;
  padding: 0 .25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<hr class="star-light">
```

Comment: Is this the latest font-awesome? `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>` is the latest way to show a solid star

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a `hr` to have a horizontal line. With a `div`, and the right combination of `relative` and `absolute` positioning, you can have a line with a star in the middle like this:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="star-light">
```

*CSS: *

```
.star-light,
.star-primary {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.star-light:after,
.star-primary:after {
  content: "\f005";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.5em;
  left: calc(50% - .5em);
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Check out the result on CodePen: https://codepen.io/kis-nagy/pen/QVRbpy

If you don't actually want a solid line, you can choose from many other border styles. https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=groove

For example, for the *groove* style, write `border: 3px groove;`

Comment: Not bad, how could a add space to the left and right of the star?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution would be adding an `i` tag with the star's class:

`<i class="fas fa-star"></i>`

And, I think, this is universal and more reliable.

Comment: I can not use the i tag, I need a line (hr) with the star in the middle of it.

Comment: I would do something like [this](https://codepen.io/Shahoud/pen/eLaZyE)